# Mysql Time Difference not working MySQL client version: 3.23.49

Tags: mysql, time, difference

TIMEDIFF function is not working 
I want to get time difference in column type=1 to when column type =1 and old_value =10 
My 2 queries as follows.

```
SELECT date_modified
FROM mantis_bug_history_table
WHERE bug_id =75616
AND TYPE =0
AND old_value =10
ORDER BY date_modified DESC 

output
------
2019-10-28 10:26:57

SELECT date_modified
FROM mantis_bug_history_table
WHERE bug_id =75616
AND TYPE =1
ORDER BY date_modified DESC

output
------
2019-10-28 10:15:04
```

[enter image description here][1]
    Error
    SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(
SELECT date_modified
FROM mantis_bug_history_table
WHERE bug_id =75616
AND TYPE =1
ORDER BY date_modified DESC ,
SELECT date_modified
FROM mantis_bug_history_table
WHERE bug_id =75616
AND TYPE =0
AND old_value =10
ORDER BY date_modified DESC )

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT date_modified
FROM mantis_bug_history_table
WHERE bu
```

the above query tried to get the time diffrence

Comment: Read the basics, try to do a simple `timediff`

Answer (score 1):

Add parenthesis `(...subquery)` around your subqueries before passing as argument to `TIMEDIFF`:

```
(SELECT date_modified FROM mantis_bug_history_table WHERE bug_id =75616 AND TYPE =0 AND old_value =10 ORDER BY date_modified DESC )

(SELECT date_modified FROM mantis_bug_history_table WHERE bug_id =75616 AND TYPE =1 ORDER BY date_modified DESC)
```

Final query:

```
 SELECT TIMEDIFF((SELECT date_modified FROM mantis_bug_history_table WHERE bug_id =75616 AND TYPE =0 AND old_value =10 ORDER BY date_modified DESC ),
 (SELECT date_modified FROM mantis_bug_history_table WHERE bug_id =75616 AND TYPE =1 ORDER BY date_modified DESC));
```

> **Please Note:** TIMEDIFF function expects only one row+col returned by each subqueries, if it is potential to have multiple in future then consider
>   adding **LIMIT 1** with both of them.

Comment: @ChathuRaaksha don't you think to accept the answer ?